# Nginx Multiple "Single Page App" routing

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

How to redirect to  begins with "/admin" url redirect to /admin/index.html (single page app)  and another pages redirect to /index.html (other single page app).

my nginx.conf is here

```
location / {
    if ( $allowed = "deny" ) { return 403; }
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}

location /admin {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/admin;
}
```

this is working but  multi level url redirect to 503 error.

sample:   get  /admin/questions/1 ->fail  503

sample:   get  /admin/questions    -> fail 503

sample    get /admin               -> ok

Comment: As far as I understand your question it does not concern regex. And would it not better be placed at serverfault?

Comment: How to do  catch all request begins with "/admin"   without regex?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it.

default.conf:

```
 root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 index index.html;

  location ~ ^/admin {       
    try_files $uri /admin/index.html;
  }

  location / {       
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
```

Comment: Still I think it would work without regex,  "location /admin/" should be enough. But anyway, if it works...

Comment: admin/index.html is a single page app. There are many route url in the page (html5 routing). If I call    www.example.com/admin/questions/1/categories   from server , it must return the just a admin/index.html . When client get this admin page,  route to /questions/1/categories  at client side.